# How do I get the value inside a <td> tag with xpath/htmlwebunit

Tags: xpath, jwebunit

I am trying to create a Java Application that retrieves information from a webpage. This is part of the code I am trying to access the value in the 1st td tag in the 2nd tr tag:

```
<TABLE  CLASS="datadisplaytable" width = "100%">
<TR>
    <TD CLASS="dddead">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Capacity</SPAN></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Actual</SPAN></TH>
    <TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" ><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Remaining</SPAN></TH>
</TR> 
<TR>
    <TH CLASS="ddlabel" scope="row" ><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Seats</SPAN></TH>
    **<TD CLASS="dddefault">46</TD>**
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">46</TD>
    <TD CLASS="dddefault">0</TD>
</TR>
```

This is what i have right now but this only returns the class of the td tag and not the value inside it:

```
List<?> table = page.getByXPath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable'][1]//tr[2]/td");
```

How would I go about getting the value of the td tag and not its properties?

edit: The code above returns this:

```
HtmlTableDataCell[<td class="dddefault">]
```

Comment: i need to get the value inside the td tag, in this case it would be '46'

Comment: It's been a while since I last used Java, but there should be a method called text(), or something similar

Comment: Hmm, I looked into what you said and found this ((HtmlTableDataCell) table.get(0)).getTextContent()

It seems to be working, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am trying to create a Java Application that retrieves information from a webpage. This is part of the code I am trying to access the value in the 1st td tag in the 2nd tr tag:

Assuming that the document is as shown in the question (`TABLE` is the top element),

**Use**:

```
/TABLE/TR[2]/TD[1]/text()
```

This selects any text-node child of the first `TD` child of the second `TR` child of the top element `TABLE`.

**In case the table is buried in the XML document, but can be uniquely identified by its `CLASS` attribute, use**:

```
//TABLE[@CLASS='datadisplaytable']/TR[2]/TD[1]/text()
```

This selects any text-node child of the first `TD` child of the second `TR` child of any (we know thre is only one such) element `TABLE` in the XML document, such that the string value of its `CLASS` attribute is the string `'datadisplaytable'`.

**Finally**, if even worse, there could be many `TABLE` elements whose `CLASS` attribute's value is `'datadisplaytable'`, and we want to select in the first such table, use:

```
(//TABLE[@CLASS='datadisplaytable'])[1]/TR[2]/TD[1]/text()
```

Comment: This helps a lot in understanding the details of xpath. I did not know it was possible to just do text(). This might be better than casting and using .getTextContent(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Saad: You can get directly the string value by using the standard XPath function `string()`.  So, `string(expressionSelectingAnElement)` returns the concatenation of all the text-node descendents of the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
for getting the text content from an element there is an xpath function called "text()" which you can use.

Element containing text 't' exactly         //*[.='t']  
Element <E> containing text 't'             //*[.='t']  
<a> containing text 't'                     //a[contains(text(),'t')]
<a> with target link 'url'                  //a[@href='url']
Link URL labeled with text 't' exactly      //a[.='t']/@href
```

If you are also using JwebUnit, there is a method "getElementTextByXPath" which can also be used to get the text.
[net.sourceforge.jwebunit.junit.WebTestCase](http://jwebunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jwebunit/junit/WebTestCase.html#getElementTextByXPath%28java.lang.String%29)

getElementTextByXPath

public String getElementTextByXPath(String xpath)
Deprecated. 
Get text of the given element.
Parameters:
xpath - xpath of the element.

```
    for (int i = 1; i != 6; i++) {

        String result = getElementTextByXPath("//td["+i+"][text()]");

        System.out.println("The Content of TD is " +result);
    }
```